# create folder using WshUserEnv

Tags: vbscript

```
Sub Copy_TNSNamesORA()
  ' Now look for SQLNET.ora file in %userprofile%\appdata\Roaming and if that exists copy the file to the
  ' the TNSNAMES folder
  Dim fso
  Dim f
  Dim wshShell
  Dim wshUserEnv
  Dim TNSFolder

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set WshUserEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
  TNSFolder = WshUserEnv("TNSNAMES")

  Dim SQLOraTempFileName
  Dim SQLOraLocalFileName
  SQLOraTempFileName = WshUserEnv("userprofile") & "\appdata\Roaming" & "\Oracle\SQLNET.ORA"
  SQLOraLocalFileName = TNSFolder & "SQLNET.ORA"
End Sub
```

I'm trying to create a folder in `c\userprofile\appdata\roaming\oracle`
named `TNSNAMES` by using this code. Can some one clarify for me that this code
`TNSFolder = WshUserEnv("TNSNAMES")` is suitable to use to create a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kby5ae3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) you create a folder by call the CreateFolder (surprise!) method of a FileSystemObject.

stolen demo code:

```
Function CreateFolderDemo
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.CreateFolder("c:\New Folder") ' <-- new folder is born
   CreateFolderDemo = f.Path ' <-- return folder spec (string) to caller
End Function
```

(Simply assigning a string containing a folder specification to a variable will copy the string but not automagically change your harddisk.)